# Not able to use github action to deploy aws beanstalk, got s3 access denied error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

I have a Github action pipeline that can successfully create an S3 and then upload my war file into there, but when deploying to the beanstalk, always got s3 access denied error. below is my build.yml file:

```
# This workflow will build a package using Maven and then publish it to GitHub packages when a release is created
# For more information see: https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#apache-maven-with-a-settings-path

name: Maven Package

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      name: Set up JDK 8

    - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '8'
        distribution: 'adopt'
        server-id: github # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
        settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

    - name: make a new dir and upload war in there
      run: mkdir staging && cp -r target/* staging

    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: Package
        path: staging

    - name: list all files
      run: ls && cd target && ls

    - name: Publish to GitHub Packages Apache Maven
      run: mvn deploy -s $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/settings.xml
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}

    - name: Deploy to EB
      uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v18
      with:
       aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
       aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
       application_name: springbootwebapi
       environment_name: Springbootwebapi-env
       version_label: v1.0.10
       region: us-east-2
       deployment_package: target/login-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war
```

below is the some log snippet from GitHub action:

> No existing bucket name given, creating/requesting storage location
> Uploading file to bucket elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-148565102071 New
> build successfully uploaded to S3,
> bucket=elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-148565102071,
> key=/springbootwebapi/v1-0-10.zip Created new application version
> v1.0.10 in Beanstalk. Starting deployment of version v1.0.10 to
> environment Springbootwebapi-env Deployment started,
> "wait_for_deployment" was true...
>
> 18:17:02 INFO: Environment update is starting. 18:17:06 ERROR:
> Service:Amazon S3, Message:Access Denied 18:17:06 ERROR: Failed to
> deploy application. 18:17:07 ERROR: Service:Amazon S3, Message:Access
> Denied: S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-148565102071,
> S3Key=resources/environments/e-fp5bx3gtdn/_runtime/_versions/springbootwebapi/v1.0.10
> 18:17:13 ERROR: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: Sample
> Application, Health: Red, Health Status: Degraded Error: Deployment
> failed: Error: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: Sample
> Application, Health: Red, Health Status: Degraded

I don't know why got accessed denied even right after the uploading successfully.

UPDATE 1:

I already have the below permissions added see the below, but not working:

[image: permissions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing `AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2` from the permission list, it works successfully. The reason is this permission actually denies several related operations to the user, see the below JSON for `AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2` details:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "iam:AddUserToGroup",
                "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachUserPolicy",
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:CreateUser",
                "iam:DetachUserPolicy",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:PutGroupPolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutUserPermissionsBoundary",
                "iam:PutUserPolicy",
                "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion",
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
                "iam:UpdateAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
                "iam:UpdateLoginProfile",
                "iam:UpdateUser",
                "lambda:AddLayerVersionPermission",
                "lambda:AddPermission",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:GetPolicy",
                "lambda:ListTags",
                "lambda:PutProvisionedConcurrencyConfig",
                "lambda:TagResource",
                "lambda:UntagResource",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "lightsail:Create*",
                "lightsail:Delete*",
                "lightsail:DownloadDefaultKeyPair",
                "lightsail:GetInstanceAccessDetails",
                "lightsail:Start*",
                "lightsail:Update*",
                "organizations:CreateAccount",
                "organizations:CreateOrganization",
                "organizations:InviteAccountToOrganization",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:DeleteBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per [docs](https://github.com/einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy#aws-permissions), you need to attach the below policies for the AWS user to be able to deploy your project when using the GitHub action you have specified:

1. `AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier`
2. `AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy`

Adding the above will fix the problem, while also ensuring that you have no future issues when using this GitHub action.

Comment: I already have those two permissions added in but still got the same error. I think the problem is more likely between beanstalk and s3 since GitHub action is able to upload to s3. I already made lots of permissions, check the screenshot. what am missing?

Comment: Beanstalk and S3 will be using the same credentials in this GitHub action apparently - regenerate your access key ID and secret key again making sure that they belong to the above user; does that work?

Comment: I regenerated several times but still not working, I only have one user for experimental purpose so there won't be any mismatch

Comment: Can you temporarily give the user full admin access? What happens then?

Comment: How to do it, there are hundreds of permissions, is there a one-step thing to make it full admin?

Comment: Created a custom policy using that JSON and added it into the existing permissions list still not working, then I suspected there must be conflicts across those existing permissions. I looked through each by each finally found out that the AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2 actually denies lots of s3 and beanstalk operations. After removing AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2, it works successfully. ironically, that thing is literally not a permission but indeed a restriction.